# MySQL 5.7 select where Unicode SMP area char equal

Tags: mysql, unicode, cjk, mysql-5.7, utf8mb4

I want to select table use character in Unicode CJK Extension-B.

```
select * from saseung where hanja = '';
```

But the result shows all CJK Extension-B characters in the table.

, , , , , etc

I guess MySQL check only the first two characters of ''.

my table def is below.

```
CREATE TABLE `saseung` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hanja` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5773 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

---

add March 4

my MySQL setting is

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME LIKE '%coll%'
OR VARIABLE_NAME LIKE '%char%' OR VARIABLE_NAME='init_connect';
```

result

[MySQL setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxASJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME like '%'
select * from hanja
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistype the query. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure table names (and other SQL constructs) are limited to `CHARACTER SET utf8mb3`.  File a bug report; it would be reasonable to move to utf8mb4.  However, there may be incompatibilities brought on by the change.

```
SELECT HEX('');  --> F0A6A48E
```

Note the 4 bytes starting with F0, hence utf8mb4.

Meanwhile, your table can *contain* utf8mb4 characters.

`init_connect` is ignored when logging in with "root".

Comment: Sorry, I mistype the query. I fixed it.

Comment: `init_connect` is ignored when logging in with "root".